# How do I Bind a Collection (IEnumerable) of a custom type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

I have the following Action to display a form with 3 items :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReferAFriend()
    {
        List<ReferAFriendModel> friends = new List<ReferAFriendModel>();
        ReferAFriendModel f1 = new ReferAFriendModel();
        ReferAFriendModel f2 = new ReferAFriendModel();
        ReferAFriendModel f3 = new ReferAFriendModel();

        friends.Add(f1);
        friends.Add(f2);
        friends.Add(f3);
        return View(friends);
    }
```

and then a Post action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReferAFriend(IEnumerable<ReferAFriendModel> friends)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid){
```

**EDIT**
My View looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ReferAFriendModel>
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_ReferAFriend", Model.ElementAt(i));
    }
```

The partial looks like this:

```
@model Models.ReferAFriendModel
<p>
   @Html.LabelFor(i => i.FullName) @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.FullName)<br />
   @Html.LabelFor(i => i.EmailAddress) @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.EmailAddress)
   @Html.HiddenFor(i=>i.Id)
</p>
```

When I post, I can see the fields are posted in the Request.Form object e.g Request.Form["FullName"] will show: "David Beckham","Thierry Henry". "Chicharito Fergurson" which are the  values I entered in the form. **But, the in the Post action,the value for 'friends' is always null.** The ReferAFriendModel has three public properties Id, EmailAddress and FullName.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably something wrong with your form/view. You should show that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) about the wire format for arrays and dictionaries. Personally I always use editor templates in my views which take care of generating proper names of the input fields so that the default model binder is able to bind the values correctly.

```
@model IEnumerable<ReferAFriendModel>
@using (Html.BEginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ReferAFriendModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ReferAFriendModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop1)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop2)
...
```

Comment: Just what I wanted, I was using an MVC2 tutorial which led me on the wrong path. Thanks